# Mysql view multiple join from other table, without several lookups

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-view

I'm trying to learn sql better, views more specifically but I can't get the following to work out for me.
I've put a slimmed down version of it here. There's more joins I have to do based on foreign keys from the tbl2 matches.

Since it's a view, I can't create temp tables.

I can't rely on stored procedures in this case.

I could do outer apply, but only to get specific references (row 1, 2...) and that would be by doing a Select * from Table2 where.... and that would mean 1 index scan per time I use it.

I could create the view using "With tbl2 (FK_TABLE1...) as SELECT FK_TABLE1 from dbo.TABLE2)  but that doesn't seem to be helpful. Each reference to it does a sort or a scan so no gain there.

Is there some way I'm able to create some type of list that I can reuse so I can simply just run 1 index scan to get the matching ones from Table2?
Or is there another way to think about this?

```
Table1  (PK, XX, YY)
Table2  (PK, FK_TABLE1, Type, Progress, ZZ, FK_Status)

Create View MyView
as

Select
    Table1.PK
    ,Table1.XX
    ,Table1.YY
    ---- I want to present data from the first 3 matches
    ,(SELECT ZZ from tbl2 where tbl2.FK_TABLE1 = FK_TABLE1.PK ORDER BY Type ASC OFFSET(0) ROWS FETCH NEXT (1) ROWS ONLY) ZZ1
    ,(SELECT ZZ from tbl2 where tbl2.FK_TABLE1 = FK_TABLE1.PK ORDER BY Type ASC OFFSET(1) ROWS FETCH NEXT (1) ROWS ONLY) ZZ2
    ,(SELECT ZZ from tbl2 where tbl2.FK_TABLE1 = FK_TABLE1.PK ORDER BY Type ASC OFFSET(2) ROWS FETCH NEXT (1) ROWS ONLY) ZZ3
    ,sts.StatusName CurrentStatus
From Table1

LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS tbl2 ON (tbl2.FK_TABLE1= Table1.PK) ---- Here I want to make some sort of join so I get all matching rows from the other table

LEFT OUTER JOIN STATUS AS sts ON (sts.PK = [tbl2 ordered by type, if last elements status = X take that, else status of first).FK_STATUS) ---- Here I'm a bit puzzled, since I have to order by, but also have a fallback value if last element isn't matching.
```

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: Simply changing the text from LEFT OUTER JOIN to LEFT JOIN wouldn't stop the 3 selects of ZZ from doing index lookups though?

Comment: I meant switch from the 3 sub-queries to a left join! (And use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.)

Comment: But the left joins would then mean I get 3x index scans (for checking FK_TABLE1) + more for each time I use the references (for joining in status based on their sorting)?
What I want to accomplish is a small collection, say 1-10 elements that's fast to sort and pick from.